# Jquery .get() works, but .load() does not

Tags: jquery, screen-scraping

I've asked a similar question before -

I have an URL - https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/authSearch.do?search=pra**&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed

That I'm on and I 'd like to call this - `$("#StanfordProfile h2").load("https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/authDetail.do?key=DR647E481&search=pra**&soundex=&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed")`

The selector works when I'm on the second page, but it's not working when I try the above command. I thought this would work because I'm loading from another page on the same website (as in I shouldn't be coming across a problem due to the same-origin policy).

Now, I tried using .get(url), with a callback function that alerts the data- that shows me the correct html- does anyone know why this would happen? Also, I'd still like to use my jquery selectors to get what I want- will that be possible?

Thank You!

EDIT-

This is the html code of the page that I'm on and am trying to load from -

```
    <div id="container_header">
<div id="topnav">
<div id="content_main">
<div id="subnav">
<div id="SWhoBody" class="stanford">
<div id="SWhoLogin">
<div id="SWhoSearch">
<div id="ResultsHead">
<div id="Toggle">
<div id="ResultsNav">
<div id="StanfordResults">
   <h2>
     <dl>
        <dt>
           <a onmouseout="swho.alone.OnMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="swho.alone.showPopup(event, 'DR647E481', 'pra**', '', 'checkbox', 'everyone', 'closed')" href="/SWApp/authDetail.do?key=DR647E481&search=pra**&soundex=&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed">Ajay Prakash</a>
</dt>
<dd>
```

This is the html I'm trying to get -

```
    <head>
<body class="stanford" onload="startstate()">
<div class="hidden">
<div id="printbanner">
<div id="container">
<div id="container_header">
<div id="topnav">
<div id="content_main">
   <div id="subnav">
   <div id="SWhoBody" class="stanford">
      <div id="SWhoLogin">
      <div id="SWhoSearch">
      <div id="ResultsHead">
      <div id="ProfileNav">
      <div id="StanfordProfile">
            <h2> Ajay Prakash </h2>
      <div id="Contact">
      <div id="HomeInfo">
      <div id="Ids">
```

I haven't used any other javascript code as I'm working from the console

Comment: I don't know if this makes any difference, but try removing the hostname portion (everything before "/SWApp") of your URL in the `.load` method.

Comment: Are you sure that "#StanfordProfile h2" exists?

Comment: I'm sure- I've tried it on that page like 5 times

Comment: Please provide us some more context to your code.

Comment: wait- what do you want to know?

Comment: I'd like to see the exact HTML you're operating on and any relevant JavaScript/jQuery code from before the line you already cited.

Comment: As mblase75 said before, "#StanfordProfile h2" doesn't exist in the page you're calling from.

Comment: it's right there- in the second html code-

  <div id="StanfordProfile">
            <h2> Ajay Prakash </h2>

Comment: Yes, underneath the heading "This is the html I'm trying to get", that's not the page you're injecting the results into. You have it backwards.

Comment: I'm trying to scrape the html from the second part of code- that's the html I'm trying to get, I'm calling .load(url) when I'm on the first page

Comment: I understand this, but $("#StanfordProfile h2").load(url)  is telling it to fetch the results and put it into $("#StanfordProfile h2"), which doesn't exist on the page you're calling from.

Comment: ahhh- now I understand- ok, so how do I take a link from the first page, load it, and then scrape from that page?

Answer (score 1):

Comment thread is getting lengthy and I think I know the answer you want now:

You can specify the items you want from the second page by putting a selector after the URL:

```
$('#StanfordResults h2').load('https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/authDetail.do?key=DR647E481&search=pra**&soundex=&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed #StanfordProfile h2');
```

You may need to change the first page selector (#StanfordResults h2) to match where you want the results placed.

The equivalent of this using $.get() in the case that you don't wish to insert the results directly into another location would be:

```
$.get('https://stanfordwho.stanford.edu/SWApp/authDetail.do?key=DR647E481&search=pra**&soundex=&stanfordonly=checkbox&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed', function(data) {
  $('#StanfordResults h2').html(data);
});
```

Rather than setting the .html() inside this callback, though, you could do whatever you want with 'data'. You're going to get the whole response HTML this way, though.

Comment: They chain, so "#StanfordProfile h2" will find the item with the ID of StanfordProfile and then find an h2 inside of it. The reverse would find all h2's that contain an item with StanfordProfile in them.

Comment: sure, but I meant the first select- #StanfordResults h2- if I'm only interested in what the second selector gets me, then does it matter what I use first?

Comment: That tells it where to put the results from the second selector. Without it, you get the results and they just get thrown away. If you only want the results and then want to manipulate them in your own custom way, don't use .load(), use .get() -- which you've seen works as intended.

Comment: wait, so will that be 
$jq.get(url #StanfordProfile h2") ?

Comment: Edited answer. I don't believe you can include a selector with a .get() call. You'll need to parse the response data for what you want and do whatever you want with it.